# Formatting Histogram from csv content with defined bucket max and min (powershell)

Tags: powershell, histogram

I have a CSV that looks like this...

```
"icon","temperatureHigh","temperatureLow","humidity","windSpeed","precipType","precipProbability"
"partly-cloudy-day","34.81","15.47","0.63","5.37","snow","0.07"
"partly-cloudy-day","36.87","28.86","0.74","10.36","snow","0.04"
"partly-cloudy-day","38.11","28.86","0.77","5.75","rain","0.27"
"clear-day","39.93","26.66","0.76","9.01","snow","0.03"
"partly-cloudy-night","46.3","29.44","0.7","3.51","rain","0.04"
...and so on
```

I am trying to use get-histogram to make a very basic histogram of the temperatureHigh columns with defined min and max and a bucket count of 5. the desired output should look like this...

```
bucketMin bucketMax count
0         16        18
16        32        121
32        48        1865
48        64        614
64        80        1811
```

Below is what i've tried, but it's wayyy off...

```
Import-Csv -Path $myCSV | Get-Histogram -Property temperatureHigh  | Select bucketMin,bucketMax,Count
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st you should state the [origin of a used cmdlet](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Statistics/1.1.53/Content/Get-Histogram.ps1) which is not part of a normal PowerShell installation.

If I interpret the code right you'll need to pass at least a `-Width`, `-Min`, `-Max`

This sample script creates 100 random numbers between -5..35

```
## Q:\Test\2019\01\11\SO_54152644.ps1

# generate random temperature between -5..35 100 sets
$Random = for($i=1;$i -lt 100;$i++){
    [pscustomObject]@{
        temperature = get-random -Minimum -5 -Maximum 35
    }
}
$Random | Get-Histogram -Property temperature -Width 5 -Min -5 -Max 35 |
    Select-Object lowerBound, upperBound, Count
```

Sample output (you might use the select to rename the columns with calculated properties):

```
> Q:\Test\2019\01\11\SO_54152644.ps1

lowerBound upperBound Count
---------- ---------- -----
        -5          0    12
         0          5    11
         5         10    15
        10         15    16
        15         20    10
        20         25    10
        25         30     9
        30         35    16
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 

If I have that origin of Get-Histogram stored as a .ps1, how can I script that to run within the current session so it creates GH cmdlet as a part of my code?

Comment: You can insert the function into your code, put it into a profile or dot source the file to contain the function in your session.